# Debian 7: no network after unplugging and plugging again the cable

Tags: networking, debian

Everytime my Debian 7 server network carrier goes down (plug/unplug, switch power cycle, etc), when it comes up there's no network connection at all (not reaching even the gateway).

To get back things I have to reboot and issue an /etc/init.d/networking restart

Nothing suspect in syslog, nor in error.log

After googling for a while, I found nothing so i'm posting here.

Any clue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know if `ip monitor` (or with timestamp: `ip -ts monitor`) was available at the time of Debian 7, but you should check this and keep one running to keep logs of network changes. I guess some tool (like NetworkManager) actively removes addresses and routes when it detects a carrier down, but fails to restore the correct settings when the carrier is back up. This could also be an hardware/driver problem about carrier detect on the NIC. The previous command would help to tell the difference

Comment: ip -t monitor uses timestamps. I'll give it a shot when everyone has left the office and no one complains about server not responding :-).
I'll be back with results.
Thanks, for now.